# classification of isometries of Euclidean space

Tags: euclidean-geometry, isometry

any isometry of Euclidean vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ has the form

$$\mathbb{R}^3\ni x\mapsto A\cdot x + b\in\mathbb{R}^3,$$

where $A\in O(3)$ is an orthonormal matrix, and $b\in\mathbb{R}^3$. However, geometrically there are only a few types of isometries, namely: **translations** (iff $A$ is the unit matrix), **rotations**, **reflections**, and compositions of those three types of geometric maps.

I am wondering, how to classify those geometric mappings in terms of $A$ and $b$? Are there any properties of $A$ and $b$, such that one can classify the isometries of Euclidean space? I looked in many books, but I could not find anything satisfactory.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: A translation corresponds to $A=I$, the identity matrix, and an arbitrary translation vector $b$, etc.

Comment: Thank you! The case of translations is not the problem here. I am interested in the "etc." Do you know a reference, where the other isometries are classified similarly to the translations (A=I)

Comment: For rotation around the origin, we have $b=0$ and and an arbitrary $A\in SO_3(\Bbb R)$, see [3D rotation group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group). In general, we have the group $O(3)\ltimes \Bbb R^3$, so the semidirect product, see the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group) for the corresponding geometric types.

Comment: Why is that the case? Cant be a map with $b\neq 0$ become a rotation?

Comment: @OliverWatt No. Not around the origin. If $T$ is a rotation around $b$, however, then  $Tx = A(x-b)+b = Ax + (b-Ab)$, where $A$ is a rotation around the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reflection is an inverse isometry, hence $\det A=-1$, whereas $\det A=1$ for a rotation.

In addition, a rotation has an invariant line, while a reflection has an invariant plane. It follows that, for a rotation, $A$ has only one unit eigenvalue, while for a reflection $A$ has two unit eigenvalues. The corresponding eigenvectors span the rotation axis or the reflection plane.